# Update all date fields of DB MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with over hundret tables and each containing a lot of columns.

My Server had the wrong date for some days and now a lot of data has this wrong date.

Is it possible to show all date fields of the whole database to update them.

But there also for example some fields like birthdate which should not be updated.

Is there any possibility for this or can I only do it manually?

Comment: Even this is IMHO off topic here: Have you considered an algorithm on how you would do this? Consider: Which datasets are effected. How should the update look like and to come back on topic here: What have you already tried?

Comment: I already know hox to update the date with adddate but I dont know how to show all columns with the same type and I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @frlan suggested, you should think on an algorithm for this update.

To get all tables and columns of type 'datetime' you can use:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    DATA_TYPE='datetime'
```

One possibility is to run this query, and in code, foreach such column, run an update query, such as:
(assuming scheme, table, column are variables from previous query)

```
UPDATE scheme.table 
SET column= ADDTIME(column, '36:00:00')
WHERE (column BETWEEN '2015-09-29 10:15:55' AND '2015-01-30 14:15:55')
```

Comment: There is an WHERE-condition missing on UPDATE as this will update just every line. But idea is good ;)

Comment: Added the required WHERE. Thanks @frlan